# xslt to get value of a pattern not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a xslt to get value of pattern from XML.

The sample XML I have is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:simpleType name="Test_Type">
    <xs:annotation />
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="16"/>
        <xs:pattern value="[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,16}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

And my xslt (1.0) is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>DataType</th>
                    <th>Pattern</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="//xs:simpleType">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test=".//xs:pattern">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select=".//xs:pattern[@value]"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am expecting a table output format like:

```
DataType Pattern 
Test_Type  [0-9a-zA-Z]{1,16}
```

But it doesn't work, please shed some lights! Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `xsl:value-of` from this...

```
<xsl:value-of select=".//xs:pattern[@value]"/>
```

To this

```
<xsl:value-of select=".//xs:pattern/@value"/>
```

The square brackets indicate a condition, so the first expression is selecting an `xs:pattern` which has a `value` attribute. It is not actually getting the `value` attribute itself.